# How can I check my UI mockups on my iphone without emailing myself the files?

Tags: gui-design, visual-design

How can I check my UI mockups on my iphone without emailing myself the files? I found a great app called "Live View" which is a remote screen viewing application, but it requires having a mac computer. Any options for PC users?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with UX; at least, not the way it is currently asked. I would say that your own UX with making the design would be helped by this being easier, of course.

Comment: @André: That is probably disputable.  I agree that it's not a very good question, but as I read it - it is about user testing methodology (http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/are-questions-on-testing-methodology-on-topic).

Comment: To me, it sounds like asking for a methodology to easily transfer files between the desktop and an iPhone. And that is exactly the answer he got.

Comment: @user: André is right.  You should improve your question.  [Take the tour in the Help Center](http://ux.stackexchange.com/helpcenter), and welcome to UX.SE :-)

Comment: @André: Yes.  In essence it's just a "transfer question".  My experience is that many UX folks makes this simple task way too complicated.  Eg. by looking for special sketching tool.  Using images is a very simple, but neat, trick.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question:

> I found a great app called "Live View" which is a remote screen viewing application, but it requires having a mac computer. Any options for PC users?

Have a search around the App Store. There are also remote desktop applications that work with PC. Splashtop is just one of them.

Comment: TeamViewer is also very popular.

Answer (score 0):

Save your images to the iCloud Photostream.
Save your images in a DropBox folder.

Test your design by showing the pictures in full-screen mode :-)

---

With this approach you can even take pictures of your hand drawn sketches and "test" them on your phone.

[image]